# How to Handle two different Objects for same Function

Tags: java, oop, object, casting

I have either one of following Objects, `ObjOne` and `ObjTwo,` going into my function, both sharing similar getters/setters.

Currently I have an intermediary, a mapper, used across internal methods, but there might be a cleaner way to do this without a mapper but lacking specific syntax.

```
public String mapper(Object obj){

   Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
   
   if(obj instanceof ObjOne){
      ObjOne obj1 = (ObjOne)obj;
      map.put("firstKey", obj1.getFirstValue());
   }
   else if(obj instanceof ObjTwo){
      ObjTwo obj2 = (ObjTwo)obj
      map.put("firstKey", obj1.getFirstValue());
   }

   return secondFunction(map);
      
}

private String secondFunction(Map<String, String> map){
   
   return thirdFunction(map.get("firstKey"));
}
```

Is there such syntax for `(ObjOne || ObjTwo)obj).getFirstValue()` to feed into `thirdFunction` herein?

Edit: I imported these Objects, so I can't declare a parent class for them, they do share getters/setters that are convenient for my scenario.

Comment: If they share the same getters/setters, they should probably have a same parent class or implement a same interface, which you can use then.

Comment: I think you have multiple typos in your code. You have a space between `instance` and `of` and both branches do the same thing, which is `map.put("firstKey", obj1.getFirstValue());`.

Comment: They unfortunately do not, I am using these objects out of an imported package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more OO approach is to compose the objects you don't control within a new object that you do control. Then write your API in terms of the object you control.

```
final class ObjOne {
    String getFirstValue() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

final class ObjTwo {
    String getFirstValue() {
        return "bar";
    }
}

class MyAdapter {
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    MyAdapter(ObjOne o1) {
        this(o1.getFirstValue());
    }

    MyAdapter(ObjTwo o2) {
        this(o2.getFirstValue());
    }

    MyAdapter(String firstKey) {
        map.put("firstKey", firstKey);
    }
}

public String secondFunction(MyAdapter adapter) {
    return thirdFunction(adapter.map.get("firstKey"));
}
```

Comment: More organized than expected, thanks! This would also help me deal with other objects with similar functions . Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion don't pass Object instead do something like this create a base model use here polymorphism. for example.

```
abstract class BaseObj {

    abstract public String getFirstValue();
}

class ObjOne extends BaseObj{


    @Override
    public String getFirstValue() {
        return  "something useful";
    }
}

class ObjTwo extends BaseObj{


    @Override
    public String getFirstValue() {
        return  "something useful";
    }
}
```

not sure what is the use case here but you can always mold accordingly.

```
public String mapper(BaseObj obj){
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("firstKey", obj.getFirstValue()); //common function call
    return secondFunction(map);

}

private String secondFunction(Map<String, String> map){

    return thirdFunction(map.get("firstKey"));
}

private String thirdFunction(String firstKey) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this would be helpful, but unfortunately these objects are outside of my control, these come as part of an imported package. Apologies, should have pointed that out in original post.

Comment: you can use reflection here to check if the method exists on that object but i doubt that will add more complexity here 